# Past the event horizon of the black hole, singularity

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, black-holes, event-horizon, singularities

Once you go past the event horizon, every path and direction leads to the singularity. Shouldn't this mean that the singularity exists in all directions and so pulls you from every direction? If that's the case, is the net force on you from the singularity zero?

Comment: It doesn't mean the singularity exists in all directions, it means you can only move in *one* direction - inward.

Answer (score 2):

Effectively, once you go past the event horizon, $r$ becomes a timelike coordinate. What that means is that, just like time, you are constantly pushed in a particular direction. Indeed, just like time, you can slow your descent by travelling in a given direction (time dilation in special relativity), but you can't avoid eventually falling in.

You can imagine being in a vast elevator: the force only pushes in one direction, but you are in principle allowed to move in any direction you like *within* the elevator.